# Parsed XML and appended it to a struct - How do I access struct variables correctly?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a xml file that I have parsed with XMLParser and appended  the values to a struc. I'm having difficulty with getting the values, however. Here's what I've done so far that I understand as a beginner.

Here's my Struct. It has 5 empty variables that I'll be getting later.

```
struct CalendarDates {
    var month = ""
    var date = ""
    var datenumber = ""
        var holiday = ""
        var description = "" }
```

Next, here is where I use XMLParser to assign value to the struct

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, XMLParserDelegate {

var myCalendarDatesStrut = [CalendarDates]()
var calendarEventsFromXML = ""
var monthsFromXML = ""
var datesFromXML = ""
var datenumbersFromXML = ""
var holidaysFromXML = ""
var descriptionsFromXML = ""

//Mark: XML Parse Delegate
extension CalendarViewController {
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
    calendarEventsFromXML = elementName
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    let data = string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    if data.count != 0 {
        switch calendarEventsFromXML
        {
        case "month": monthsFromXML = data
        case "date": datesFromXML = data
        case "datenumber": datenumbersFromXML = data
        case "holiday": holidaysFromXML = data
        default: break
        }}}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if elementName == "calendarevent"
    {
        var myCalendarDates = CalendarDates()
        myCalendarDates.month = monthsFromXML
        myCalendarDates.date = datesFromXML
        myCalendarDates.datenumber = datenumbersFromXML
        myCalendarDates.holiday = holidaysFromXML
        myCalendarDatesStrut.append(myCalendarDates)
    }}}}
```

Alright, so here's where I'm running into a block. I want to get all of the dates (datesFromXML) so that I can match them to some visible Dates and do some method.

I tried

```
let datesFromCalendarXML = myCalendarDatesStrut.date
```

But this gives me an error Value of type '[CalendarDates]' has no member 'date'. Didn't I append these to this this struc when I parsed the xml? Did I do it wrong?

Comment: `myCalendarDatesStrut` is an array, arrays don't have a `date` property.

Comment: It's not a date property, but a var that Im trying to parse from my XML. I should change its name.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
let datesFromCalendarXML = myCalendarDatesStrut.map {$0.date} // this gives [Date]
```

since `myCalendarDatesStrut` is an array and not a single object you can't use dot operator with it , after that you can filter this array

```
let date1 = //
let date2 = //
let result = datesFromCalendarXML.filter { $0 > date1 && $0 < date2 } // filter to whatever you want
```